# ThingsBoard telemetry export only provides one data point

Tags: thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

I installed ThingsBoard (TB) 3.3.2 at Rasperry Pi, added a device and sent some temperature values to it. Those values can be seen at my TB dashboard.

The problem is, when I try to request those data by TB telemetry API, I can only received one value (i.e. 'data point') - which is the most recent one.

For instance: when I send this API call (I have hidden my IPv4 address)...

*curl -v -X GET "http://x.x.x.x:8080/api/plugins/telemetry/DEVICE/$ENTITYID/values/timeseries?keys=temperature&startTs=1639458000&interval=60000&limit=100&agg=AVG" 

--header "Content-Type:application/json" 

--header "X-Authorization:Bearer $JWT_TOKEN"*

...I just receive only this single data point - and not all of the existing ones:

{"temperature":[{"ts":1639670432016,"value":"25.8"}]}

When I send an other temperature value to the device of TB, let's say 26.3, and repeat the curl command above, then I get the new value but not the other ones, even not the one I have seen before (25.8):

{"temperature":[{"ts":1639673228689,"value":"26.3"}]}

I tried it with some different URL-line params, e.g. with and without the tags 'agg', 'limit', and 'startTs'. But it didn't result in providing more than only one data point.

Does anybody know how to get *all* historical data points within the range as definde by startTs(/endTs) and not only the most recent one?

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks!

[ThingsBoard dashboard showing my historical data points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Gf1.png)

BTW: If I use *endTs* (e.g.: ...keys=temperature&startTs=1639458000&endTs=1640037600&interval=60000...) TB simply returns: "{}". But that seems to be a different issue?

Comment: Firstly try putting your start and end times in millisecond (you have them in seconds). You need to specify both a start and end time. Set `startTs=0`, and `endTs=current time` (eg 1639691968000). The only params you need are `keys`, `startTs`, `endTs`. See the documentation here: https://cloud.thingsboard.io/swagger-ui/#/telemetry-controller/getTimeseriesUsingGET

Comment: Thank you JacksonB! Your advice solved the problem. I was converting datetime to unix time by using a website and didn't mention that the output was in seconds instead of ms.